# From Python to Excel - Building an excel worksheet

Tags: python, excel, database

With the help of some very kind people on here I finally got a working script to scrape some data. I now desire to transfer this data from Python to Excel, in a specific format. I have tried multiple approaches, but did not manage to get the desired result.

My script is the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def analyze(i):
    url = f"https://ktarena.com/fr/207-dofus-world-cup/match/{i}/1"
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    arena = soup.find("span", attrs=('name')).text
    title = soup.select_one("[class='team'] .name a").text
    point = soup.select(".result .points")[0].text
    image_titles = ', '.join([i['title'] for i in soup.select("[class$='dead'] > img")])

    title_ano = soup.select("[class='team'] .name a")[1].text
    point_ano = soup.select(".result .points")[1].text
    image_titles_ano = ', '.join([i['title'] for i in soup.select("[class='class'] > img")])

    print((title,point,image_titles),(title_ano,point_ano,image_titles_ano),arena)


for i in range(46270, 46394):  
    analyze(i)
```

To summarize, I scrape a couple of things:

- Team names (title & title_ano)
- Image titles (image_titles & image_titles_ano)
- Team points (points & points_ano)
- A string of text (arena)

One line of output currently looks like this:

```
('Thunder', '0 pts', 'roublard, huppermage, ecaflip') ('Tweaps', '60 pts', 'steamer, feca, sacrieur') A10
```

My goal is to transfer this output to excel, making it look like this:

[image: What I desire]

To clarify, in terms of the variables I have it would be this:
[image: What I desire in terms of my variables]

Currently I can manage to transfer my data to excel, but I can't figure out how to format my data this way. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the code that you are using is not actually wholly correct. E.g.:

```
analyze(46275)
(('Grind', '10 pts', 'roublard, ecaflip'), 
('SOLARY', '50 pts', 'enutrof, eniripsa, steamer, eliotrope'), 'A10')
```

Notice that the first player only has *two* image titles, and the second one has *four*. This is incorrect, and happens because your code assumes that `img` tags with the `class` ending in "dead" belong to the first player, and the ones that have a `class` named "class" belong to the second. This happens to be true for your first match (i.e. `https://ktarena.com/fr/207-dofus-world-cup/match/46270`), but very often this is not true at all. E.g. if I compare my result below with the same method applied to your `analyze` function, I end up with mismatches is 118 rows out of 248.

Here's a suggested rewrite:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

def analyze_new(i):
    # You don't need `/1` at the end of the url
    url = f"https://ktarena.com/fr/207-dofus-world-cup/match/{i}"
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    
    arena = soup.find('span',class_='name').get_text()
    
    # find all teams, and look for info inside each team
    teams = soup.findAll('div',class_='team')
    my_teams = [tuple()]*2
    for idx, team in enumerate(teams):
        my_teams[idx] = my_teams[idx] + \
            (team.select(".name a")[0].get_text(),)
        my_teams[idx] = my_teams[idx] + \
            (soup.select(".result .points")[idx].get_text(),)
        my_teams[idx] = my_teams[idx] + \
            (', '.join([img['title'] for img in team.findAll('img')[1:]]),)

    # notice, we need `return` instead of `print` to use the data     
    return *my_teams,arena

print(analyze_new(46275))
(('Grind', '10 pts', 'roublard, ecaflip, enutrof'), 
('SOLARY', '50 pts', 'eniripsa, steamer, eliotrope'), 'A10')
```

Before writing this data to excel, I would create a [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), which can then be exported very easily:

```
# capture info per player in a single row
rows = []

for i in range(46270, 46394):
    one, two, arena = analyze_new(i)
    # adding `i` to rows, as "Match" seems like a useful `column` to have!
    # but if not, you can delete `i` here below (N.B. do NOT delete the COMMA!)
    # and cut 'Match' twice below
    rows.append(one+(arena,i))
    rows.append(two+(arena,i))

cols = ['Team','Points', 'Images', 'Arena','Match']

# create df
df = pd.DataFrame(data=rows,columns=cols)

# split up the images strings in `df.Images` and make new columns for them
# finally, drop the `df.Images` column itself
df = pd.concat([df,
                df.Images.str.split(',',expand=True)\
                    .rename(columns={i:f'Image Title {i+1}' 
                                     for i in range(3)})], axis=1)\
    .drop('Images', axis=1)

# Strip " pts" from the strings in `df.Points` and convert the type to an `int`
df['Points'] = df.Points.str.replace(' pts','').astype(int)

# Re-order the columns
df = df.loc[:, ['Match', 'Arena','Team', 'Image Title 1', 'Image Title 2', 
                'Image Title 3', 'Points']]

print(df.head())

   Match Arena         Team Image Title 1 Image Title 2 Image Title 3  Points
0  46270   A10      Thunder      roublard    huppermage       ecaflip       0
1  46270   A10       Tweaps       steamer          feca      sacrieur      60
2  46271   A10   Shadow Zoo          feca      osamodas       ouginak       0
3  46271   A10  UndisClosed      eniripsa          sram       pandawa      60
4  46272   A10   Laugh Tale      osamodas       ecaflip           iop       0

# Finally, write the `df` to an Excel file
df.to_excel('fname.xlsx')
```

Result:

[image: df_to_excel]

If you dislike the default styles added to the `header` row and `index` column, you can write it away like so:

```
df.T.reset_index().T.to_excel('test.xlsx', index=False, header=False)
```

Result:

[image: df_to_excel_ex_header_index]

Incidentally, I assume you have a particular reason for wanting the function to return the relevant data as `*my_teams,arena`. If not, it would be better to let the function itself do most of the heavy lifting. E.g. we could write something like this, and return a `df` directly.

```
def analyze_dict(i):
    url = f"https://ktarena.com/fr/207-dofus-world-cup/match/{i}"
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    
    d = {'Match': [i]*2,
               'Arena': [soup.find('span',class_='name').get_text()]*2,
               'Team': [],
               'Image Title 1': [],
               'Image Title 2': [],
               'Image Title 3': [],
               'Points': [],
               }
    
    teams = soup.findAll('div',class_='team')
    for idx, team in enumerate(teams):
        d['Team'].append(team.select(".name a")[0].get_text())
        d['Points'].append(int(soup.select(".result .points")[idx].get_text().split(' ')[0]))
        for img_idx, img in enumerate(team.findAll('img')[1:]):
            d[f'Image Title {img_idx+1}'].append(img['title'])
        
    return pd.DataFrame(d)

print(analyze_dict(46275))

   Match Arena    Team Image Title 1 Image Title 2 Image Title 3  Points
0  46275   A10   Grind      roublard       ecaflip       enutrof      10
1  46275   A10  SOLARY      eniripsa       steamer     eliotrope      50
```

Now, we only need to do the following outside the function:

```
dfs = []

for i in range(46270, 46394):
    dfs.append(analyze_dict(i))

df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

print(df.head())


   Match Arena         Team Image Title 1 Image Title 2 Image Title 3  Points
0  46270   A10      Thunder      roublard    huppermage       ecaflip       0
1  46270   A10       Tweaps       steamer          feca      sacrieur      60
2  46271   A10   Shadow Zoo          feca      osamodas       ouginak       0
3  46271   A10  UndisClosed      eniripsa          sram       pandawa      60
4  46272   A10   Laugh Tale      osamodas       ecaflip           iop       0
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the detailed answer. You're the real deal, can't thank you enough@!

Answer (score 1):

With hardly any changes from your post, you can use the [openpyxl](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/) library to write the output to an excel file as shown below:

```
import requests
from openpyxl import Workbook
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def analyze(i):
    url = f"https://ktarena.com/fr/207-dofus-world-cup/match/{i}/1"
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    arena = soup.find("span", attrs=('name')).text
    title = soup.select_one("[class='team'] .name a").text
    point = soup.select(".result .points")[0].text
    image_titles = image_titles = [i['title'] for i in soup.select("[class='team']:nth-of-type(1) [class^='class'] > img")]
    try:
        image_title_one = image_titles[0]
    except IndexError: image_title_one = ""
    try:
        image_title_two = image_titles[1]
    except IndexError: image_title_two = ""
    try:
        image_title_three = image_titles[2]
    except IndexError: image_title_three = ""
    
    ws.append([arena,title,image_title_one,image_title_two,image_title_three,point])
    
    title_ano = soup.select("[class='team'] .name a")[1].text
    point_ano = soup.select(".result .points")[1].text
    image_titles_ano = [i['title'] for i in soup.select("[class='team']:nth-of-type(2) [class^='class'] > img")]
    try:
        image_title_ano_one = image_titles_ano[0]
    except IndexError: image_title_ano_one = ""
    try:
        image_title_ano_two = image_titles_ano[1]
    except IndexError: image_title_ano_two = ""
    try:
        image_title_ano_three = image_titles_ano[2]
    except IndexError: image_title_ano_three = ""

    ws.append([arena,title_ano,image_title_ano_one,image_title_ano_two,image_title_ano_three,point_ano])
    print((title,point,image_titles),(title_ano,point_ano,image_titles_ano),arena)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wb = Workbook()
    wb.remove(wb['Sheet'])
    ws = wb.create_sheet("result")
    ws.append(['Arena','Team','Image Title 1','Image Title 2','Image Title 3','Points'])
    for i in range(46270, 46290):  
        analyze(i)
    wb.save("output.xlsx")
```

I've fixed the selectors to grab the right number of image titles.